# How to find out classes in PHP that has implemented a particular interface in visual studio

Tags: php, visual-studio, inheritance, logging, data-structures

**Scenario:**

**There is a interface:**

```
LoggerInterface{

}
```

**Which is implemented by Class A and B**

```
Class A implements LoggerInterface{

}

Class B implements LoggerInterface{

}
```

**Now, I only Know that where is LoggerInterface file present, But I also want to know which classes implemented it.**

NOTE: Other answers available are following .NET and also didn't have a clear solution

Comment: Find by word `implements LoggerInterface` or do you want to do it in runtime?

Comment: I want to do it by right click